# Laravel 5.1 Mail::raw works but Mail::send doesn't

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.1, amazon-ses

I am using `Laravel 5.1` email with `Amazon SES`.

If I use:

```
Mail::send('mymail', function ($m) use ($user)  or Mail::send('mymail', $data, function ($m) use ($user)
```

It doesn't work.  I get a `500 error`.

However if I use:

```
Mail::raw('Hello this is a test message', function ($m) use ($user)
```

It works fine.

Any thoughts what could be causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423677/laravels-mail-notification-wont-send-but-laravels-mailraw-will)

Comment: I looked at the link above and modified mail.php accordingly.  Still it doesn't work.